# How to replace a fixed position character of a string?

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a file having a string `AKASHMANDAL`

I want to replace 7th positioned character (whatever the character may be) with "D"

Output will looks like

```
AKASHMDNDAL
```

I tried with the following command which only add the character after 7th position

```
sed -E 's/^(.{7})/\1D/' file
```

This gives me `AKASHMADNDAL`

How can I replace the character instead of just adding?

Answer (score 4):

Substitute any character in the 7th position using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/./D/7' input_file
AKASHMDNDAL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply match one character outside of the capture group:

```
sed  -E 's/^(.{6})./\1D/'
```

*(notice the dot outside the parenthesis)*

Answer (score 2):

If you can consider an `awk` solution. `awk` can handle it better without regex and with more power to tweak based on positions:

```bash
awk '{print substr($0,1,6) "D" substr($0,8)}' file

AKASHMDNDAL
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Here is the [Online demo](https://ideone.com/pEGEuY) for used `awk` code here.

```
awk -v RS='^.{7}' '
RT{
  sub(/.$/,"",RT)
  ORS=RT"D"
  print
}
END{
  ORS=""
  print
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: @Akash Mondal, could you please do let us know, how these solutions went for you? Thank you.